# How is JAVA_HOME not set but Gradle can still run?

Tags: java, gradle

**Please note:** This question is **not** a dupe, anyone who reads it will see that. I'm not asking *How do I find JAVA_HOME` on my Mac?* I'm asking how is Gradle running when JAVA_HOME is not set. Two totally different questions. The difference is even in the title. Read the questions thoroughly people!

---

Mac 10.11.6 (El Capitan) Java developer here. I've had my machine more than a year and have been building Java apps on it the entire time.

In the terminal, if I run `echo $JAVA_HOME` the output is empty/blank:

```
myMachine:myDir myUser$ echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Zip. Nadda. Nothin'. But then if I run `which java` I get:

```
myMachine:myDir myUser$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

So Java is installed but `$JAVA_HOME` is somehow empty/null/blank.

If I clone [this repo](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/scala-guice-example) and run `./gradlew run` it executes perfectly:

```
./gradlew run
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileScala
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:run
Hello!

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 8.478 secs
```

I'm wondering: if `JAVA_HOME` isn't set, then how is Gradle even running successfully?! **Shouldn't `$JAVA_HOME` have been set when Java was installed via `brew`?**

---

### Update:

When I do `echo $PATH` I see:

```
/Users/myUser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin
/Users/myUser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/bin
/Users/myUser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
/Users/myUser/.sdkman/candidates/scala/current/bin
/Users/myUser/.sdkman/candidates/sbt/current/bin
/Users/myUser/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current/bin
/Users/myUser/.sdkman/candidates/lazybones/current/bin
/Users/myUser/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/bin
/Users/myUser/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current/bin
/Users/myUser/.sdkman/candidates/ant/current/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/opt/X11/bin
/usr/local/go/bin
/Users/myUser/.rvm/bin
/Users/myUser/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: Not a dupe in any way shape or form, please remove the dupe flag on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation says:

```
Gradle uses whatever JDK it finds in your path.
Alternatively, you can set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the 
installation directory of the desired JDK.
```

Check your path variable and values of it, maybe Java already pointed there.

Comment: Thanks @GarRudo (+1) - please see my update that includes everything on my `$PATH`. Any new ideas? Thanks again! Again, I **know** I can manually set `$JAVA_HOME` myself...I'm wondering how Gradle is even finding a Java installation in the first place!

Comment: Saw your update. If you installed JDK with brew and java is not on your path, there must be another variable where brew stores it's values. I don't know for sure since I never used brew. If there is no JDK or JRE somewhere in the variables, Gradle wouldn't run.

Comment: Ahh I might be on to something. Note that it's `./gradlew run` (Gradle Wrapper). Could the Gradle Wrapper be managing its own version of Java somehow?

Comment: I don't think so. Nothing I see about that in documentations, and that would be something important to mention than.

Comment: Thanks again, but I feel like I'm missing something. I don't think it should matter where brew installed Java...if Gradle just looks in `$PATH` and my `$PATH` doesn't have Java on it...how the hell is Gradle working?!?

Comment: I have an idea. You are checking user variables, but what about system variables? I don't know how it works on Mac, but in Windows there is User variables and System variables.

Comment: Ahhh, thats it, `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`. So weird - thanks @GarRudo!